# How to approach the following boundary value problem on the unit ball: $\Delta u(x,y)=| x|$, $u(x,y)=0$ for $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, laplacian

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory but I'm elaborating just in case: let $u\in C^{2}(D(0,1),\mathbb{R})$ (where $D(0,1)$ is the (open) unit disk centered at $0$) such that the laplacian of $u$ equals $\mid x\mid$ on $D(0,1)$ and $u=0$ on $\partial D(0,1)$. I know the solution can be computed using Green's function but I'm not entirely sure how to do it in this example. I would very much appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: For ${} = \vert x\vert$ did you mean ${} = (x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$? Probably not, only checking so that things are clear.

Comment: From my understanding of the problem, no. I meant $u(x,y)=\mid\,x\mid$. That is, u agrees with the absolute value of the variable $x$ when we see it as a two variable function. To be honest, I'm not the one looking for an answer. A friend of mine asked me to post this question because he doesn't speak English very well. This isn't my area of expertise either, so I'm not of much help.

Answer (score 0):

Let me sketch the solution. First, notice that $v(x,y):=\frac{|x|^3}{6}$ satisfies the equation $\Delta v(x,y)=|x|$, but *not* the boundary condition $v(x,y)=0$ at $r:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$. Instead, it satisfies (in polar coordinates) the boundary condition $v(r=1,\phi)=\frac{1}{6}|\cos\phi\,|^3$. Let's then consider the function $w:=u-v$. From the definition of $v$, it follows that $w$ satisfies Laplace's equation
$$
\Delta w=\Delta u - \Delta v = 0 \tag{1}
$$
with boundary condition
$$
w(r=1,\phi)=u(r=1,\phi)-v(r=1,\phi)=-\frac{1}{6}|\cos\phi\,|^3. \tag{2}
$$
The general solution to $(1)$ in polar coordinates is given by$^{(*)}$
$$
w(r,\phi)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n(a_n\cos n\phi + b_n\sin n\phi), \tag{3}
$$
which has the form of a Fourier series. To determine its coefficients, we use the boundary condition $(2)$, which yields
\begin{align}
a_0&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(-\frac{1}{6}|\cos\phi\,|^3\right) dx, \tag{4a} \\
a_n&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(-\frac{1}{6}|\cos\phi\,|^3\right)\cos n\phi\, dx, \tag{4b} \\
b_n&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(-\frac{1}{6}|\cos\phi\,|^3\right)\sin n\phi\, dx. \tag{4c}
\end{align}
Once these integrals are calculated, the solution to the original PDE is given by
$u(r,\phi)=v(r,\phi)+w(r,\phi)$, where $v(r,\phi)=\frac{r^3}{6}|\cos\phi\,|^3$ and $w(r,\phi)$ is given by $(3)$ and $(4)$.

---

$^{(*)}$ See, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation#In_two_dimensions.